# Greensock - changing speed to TweenMax transition

Tags: javascript, gsap

I am just getting to grips with **GSAP** and so far it's really nice. However, does anyone know how I can slow the animation down on this?

JavaScript:

```
TweenMax.to(players, 0.5, {bottom: "-250"})
```

I am basically using that to move a `div` down and out of position but it does it rather fast and I want to slow it down.

Comment: [The second parameter is the duration of the transition.](https://greensock.com/docs/#/HTML5/GSAP/TweenLite/to/)

Comment: Yep worked it out, thanks mate

Answer (score 2):

To slow the animation down without adjusting your `duration` you can also try adding any of the following to the GSAP special `ease` property.

Checkout the GSAP Ease Visualizer:

http://greensock.com/ease-visualizer

Available ease methods:

- [Power0](http://greensock.com/docs/#/HTML5/GSAP/Easing/Power0/)
- [Power1](http://greensock.com/docs/#/HTML5/GSAP/Easing/Power1/)
- [Power2](http://greensock.com/docs/#/HTML5/GSAP/Easing/Power2/)
- [Power3](http://greensock.com/docs/#/HTML5/GSAP/Easing/Power3/)
- [Power4](http://greensock.com/docs/#/HTML5/GSAP/Easing/Power4/)
- [Back](http://greensock.com/docs/#/HTML5/GSAP/Easing/Back/)
- [Elastic](http://greensock.com/docs/#/HTML5/GSAP/Easing/Elastic/)
- [Bounce](http://greensock.com/docs/#/HTML5/GSAP/Easing/Bounce/)
- [RoughEase](http://greensock.com/docs/#/HTML5/GSAP/Easing/RoughEase/)
- [SlowMo](http://greensock.com/docs/#/HTML5/GSAP/Easing/SlowMo/)
- [SteppedEase](http://greensock.com/docs/#/HTML5/GSAP/Easing/SteppedEase/)
- [Circ](http://greensock.com/docs/#/HTML5/GSAP/Easing/Circ/)
- [Expo](http://greensock.com/docs/#/HTML5/GSAP/Easing/Expo/)
- [Sine](http://greensock.com/docs/#/HTML5/GSAP/Easing/Sine/)
- [Strong](http://greensock.com/docs/#/HTML5/GSAP/Easing/Strong/)
- [Quad](http://greensock.com/docs/#/HTML5/GSAP/Easing/Quad/)
- [Quart](http://greensock.com/docs/#/HTML5/GSAP/Easing/Quart/)
- [Quint](http://greensock.com/docs/#/HTML5/GSAP/Easing/Quint/)

Available Ease Types:

- ease
- easeIn
- easeOut
- easeInOut

GSAP ease Docs:

http://greensock.com/docs/#/HTML5/GSAP/Easing/

You can even create a custom function to customize your ease function:

http://greensock.com/docs/#/HTML5/GSAP/Easing/Ease/

When animating it is always best to animate `x` and `y` versus `top`, `bottom`, `right`, and `left` .. for a smoother animation on a sub-pixel level.